# I had already install strongloop, but it still didn't work when I type "slc loopback" at prompt

Tags: node.js, strongloop, loopback

My computer is Win7， first I install strongloop globally, and the result as below:

[image: The result of installing strongloop on my Win7 computer]

[The result of installing strongloop on my Win7 computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhbmG.jpg)

Then I type "slc loopback" at my prompt, the result made me confused as below:

[image]

[Failed to running loopback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atbxo.jpg)

It says, "slc" is not an internal or external command, nor can it be a running program or batch file. How can I deal with this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @propagated: thanks for inlining the pictures here in your edit. If you do that in the future, would you put them in their own separate paragraph? That prevents them from attaching to a prior or following sentence, which puts either the image or text at a strange page position. Thanks!